# Minimal mine track

Tags: building, trains, piece-usage

I want to create a mine scene on a 32x32 baseplate. I want to run a train track across the front, and then about 12 studs into the mine. Then, I want to build a couple simple mining carts on the tracks.  I'm not very familiar with the tracks pieces.  Can someone help me plan the pieces I'll need for this?

Comment: I'm not looking to do anything electric.

Answer (score 10):

I think you want to consider using the 4-stud-wide "rollercoaster" tracks, part numbers [25059](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=25059), [25061](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=25061) and [26022](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=26022).

Here's how those to parts look like in [set 60228](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=60228-1):

[image: Set 60228 closeup]

The straight track are 8 or 16 studs long, and the 90° curved track has a radius of 12 studs (counted from the track centerline). These dimensions allow for a few track pieces to be placed in a 32x32 baseplate comfortably.You can fit a "L" made of one 90° curved track and two lengths of straight tracks (16 studs long each) into a 32x32 baseplate, leaving a margin of 2 studs.

This quick-and-dirty LeoCAD diagram should help convey the idea:

[image: LeoCAD diagram with "L" track]

Also note that part [85976 "Train, Track Plastic, Narrow, Curve"](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=85976) does exist, and is also 4 studs wide. However, there is no (official) corresponding flat straight part, and the curve radius is wider (24 studs). You can fit two such track parts in a 32x32 baseplate, but beware of the half-a-stud-long connectors at the end of each track piece, which might overhang:

[image: LeoCAD diagram with 4-stud track]

For the carts I guess you'll want to use parts [50254 "Train Wheel Small"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=50254) and [4600 "Modified 2x2 Plate with Wheels Holder"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4600) or the [roller coaster car assembly](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=26021c01) made up of [26061 "Roller Coaster Car Base"](https://rebrickable.com/parts/26021/vehicle-base-roller-coaster-car-4-x-5/) and [24869 "Roller Coaster Wheels"](https://rebrickable.com/parts/24869/wheel-roller-coaster/).

The later is the technique used in set [60188 "Mining experts site"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=60188-1), altough the result doesn't look "minecarty" enough to me since the wheels themselves are obscured from view:

[image: Mine cart detail from set 60188]

Comment: Note that even though there is no premade LEGO flat straight narrow track, you can use either LEGO’s individual rail pieces to do the flat part, or you can buy flat straight track from one of the third party track companies (I think TrixBrix makes them but I could be wrong).

Comment: You're right, I could find https://trixbrix.eu/en_US/c/Narrow-Gauge/26 and https://www.4dbrix.com/products/train/2-08-narrow/ . I wonder if those could be elaborated into another answer?

Answer (score 6):

There have already been a few older sets containing pre-made mine carts or similar constructions with tracks besides the currently used style mentioned by IvanSanchez, take a look at how they were implemented:

1. Indiana Jones and [The Temple of Doom (7199)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=84809#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D):

[image]

2. [The Dynamic Duo Funhouse Escape (6857)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6857-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D):
   [image]
3. [Amusement Park Roller Coaster (41130)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=41130-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D):
   [image]
4. [Silver Mine Shootout (79110)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=79110-1&name=Silver%20Mine%20Shootout&category=%5BThe%20Lone%20Ranger%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D):
   [image]
5. [The Mine (4204)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=4204-1&name=The%20Mine&category=%5BTown%5D%5BCity%5D%5BConstruction%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D), using different parts:
   [image]
6. [Dwarves' Mine (7036)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7036-1&name=Dwarves%27%20Mine&category=%5BCastle%5D%5BFantasy%20Era%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D):
   [image]
7. [The Mine (21118)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=21118-1&name=The%20Mine&category=%5BMinecraft%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D), not rolling:
   [image]
8. [The Precious Crystal Mine (41177)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=41177-1&name=The%20Precious%20Crystal%20Mine&category=%5BElves%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D), also not rolling:
   [image]
9. [The Creeper Mine (21155)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=21155-1&name=The%20Creeper%20Mine&category=%5BMinecraft%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D), another style of non-rolling implementation with decorative "wheels":
   [image]
10. [Bandit's Secret Hide-Out (6761)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6761-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D), rather a cannon on tracks than a minecart, but could be adapted:

[image]

---

The relevant parts from the Silver Mine set, added based on the request for clarification:

[image]

Comment: 5 and 6 (at least) are interesting in that they adapt the normal rail tracks using different wheels, and these can be easier to get hold of

Comment: I like the mining cart in the Silver mine shootout. I can't find the diagrams for it in the instructions. Can someone help me understand how to build something like that?

Comment: @MonteGardner The instructions for the track and cart are found in on pages 4 and 14 of the [instruction booklet](https://www.lego.com/cdn/product-assets/product.bi.core.pdf/6063286.pdf), but I have added the relevant parts as image to the answer. The cart is a nice SNOT build, surprise :)