# Alternative ways of attaching roller coaster wheels

Tags: building, piece-usage, snot

While doing a bit of research about a [mine track related question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/16545/minimal-mine-track), I noticed that part [24869 "Wheel Roller Coaster"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=24869) is meant to be used only with part 26021 to form a form [a specific assembly](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=26021c01):

[image: Roller coaster car assembly]

I personally don't like the aesthetics of the car base, so I'm wondering about how to use the wheels without the car base. The axle has the same dimensions of a bar, so it can be used with clip plates or minifig hands:

[image: Attaching wheels to clips]

...but that will obviously have a lot of friction.

What building techniques and parts can be used to attach the roller coaster wheels (or, for that matter, any other bar part) to other parts **with low enough friction**?

I'm looking for techniques for play (i.e. the vehicle should move along tracks and hold together when shaken), not for display (which can be achieved by high-friction clips).

Comment: Without the rollercoaster parts to check, I reckon some of the smaller wheel assemblies might be compatible, but not [the one I was thinking of](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2655c06&name=Plate,%20Round%202%20x%202%20Thin%20with%20Wheel%20Holder%20and%20Dark%20Purple%20Trolley%20Wheels%20(2655%20/%202496)&category=%5BPlate,%20Round%5D#T=C&C=86) as the bar has smaller sections where itc lips in

Comment: @Chris that part clips onto the narrower parts of the wheel piece, not the middle, where it is the usual bar diameter.

Comment: @zovits, exactly. That's why I said not that one. I still think there's another but couldn't find anything

Comment: @ChrisH Right, sorry, I misread your comment and made the same point as you did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like the other answer by @matthew jensen, I do not have the roller coaster wheels in my possession, so my answer is entirely based on what seems to work in Stud.io.

It looks like you can construct a basic wheelholder using [part 3176 - Plate 2x3 with Hole](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3176&name=Plate,%20Modified%202%20x%203%20with%20Hole&category=%5BPlate,%20Modified%5D#T=C). Here is how I would do this:

[image]

I am using 2 small 1x2 - 1x2 inverted brackets and a 2x3 plate in the above.

Here is how you would use the same (replacing the 2x3 plate with a 3x3 plate) to create a small minecart that (hopefully) rolls along the track. If a 5 stud wheelbase is too long to make it through LEGO rollercoaster track curves, you can shorten the build by 1 or 2 studs.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've checked this assembly in LDCad. Roller coaster wheels indeed fit into the space. Based on the results I can see in LDCad small pins protruding from each side may be a little too short and barely have any plastic to hold on to plates. I'm not even sure if wheels would stay in place in case of a tiny bump or misalignment. However, it feels like this could work if which ever assembly will be put on top of these wheels will be static.

Comment: I've been fiddling a bit with LeoCAD about using other pieces for this technique. It seems that the outer rim of the wheel has the right dimensions to accept a round 1x1 brick (on *either* end), so trying to use any piece to fit tighter might actually provide a solid connection (instead of allowing the wheel to spin).

Answer (score 5):

Disclaimer: I don't have the roller coaster wheels or body, and have not tried this.

The [Skateboard with mag wheels](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=45917c01&name=Minifigure,%20Utensil%20Skateboard%20with%20Mag%20Wheel%20Holders%20and%20White%20Mag%20Wheels&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Utensil%5D#T=C) comes to mind, as an example of a bar connection with little friction.
[image]

If I remember correctly, the wheel bars are of normal diameter (regular clips have normal friction), so it is the board clips which are slightly larger than a regular clip.

Comment: This is a good approach, but not without drawbacks. The rollercoaster wheels might slide sideways and hit the sides of the top part of the skateboard. It also forces a fixed axle distance that might cause trouble with narrow curves.

Answer (score 4):

The diameter of a bar (i.e. the axle) is the same as the distance between two studs. This can be leveraged in a variety of ways using hollow studs and bars.

This uses upside-down [85861 1x1 round plate](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=85861)s and short bar parts ([48729](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=48729)):

[image: LeoCAD diagram]
[image: LeoCAD diagram]

The hollow studs can be moved up and down in order to adjust the friction.

Same technique, using [3959 Minifig Utensil, Torch](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3959) and [11203 2x2 inverted tile](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11203):

[image: LeoCAD diagram]
[image: LeoCAD diagram]

The friction on the axle will depend on how deep the torch is pushed into the inverted tile.

A few [2555 1x1 tile with clip](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2555) and an upside-down [4238 trunk lid](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4238) (from the silver mine set), and we've got ourselves a minecart:

[image: LeoCAD diagram]