Do rollercoaster wheels clip into any part other than the rollercoaster base?
Normally the rollercoater wheels (part 24869) clip into the dedicated rollercoaster base (part 26021).  Does anyone know of any other parts these wheels will clip into and rotate as smoothly?  Part number 8, for example?  I would prefer if the part is 4 studs wide and the clips are on the outside.
The reason I am interested is I would like some of my rollercoaster cars not to have the small pin underneath as too many cars with pins don't necessarily align very well with chain belts (made of parts 3711) to push the train along.  So I would like to build some of the cars without the underside pins.  I have an alternative solution using wheels 50254 but ideally, I would prefer to use the rollercoaster wheels.

Possible duplicate of https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/16548/13403

Indeed, thank you for directing me to that post, it hadn't come up in my searches.  I'll try solutions such as you suggested there.

What is this "Part number 8" ?

It’s this one: https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=8#T=C.  Very old part typically found on a motorbike in sets I had in the 70s.
