Which part(s) can be connected to "rocker plate" (30166) such that it rotates freely?
If I mount the "rocker plate" (part 30166) via its bar handle onto a "Tile, Modified 1 x 1 with Open O Clip" (part 15712) there is too much friction for the rocker plate to rotate freely.

Which part(s), most similar to part 15712, could replace it in such a configuration so that the rocker plate does rotate freely?

See https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/16548/13403 - the rollercoaster base and the skateboard base might be viable options for a low-friction bar connection.
